# Switch Filters with VideoCore VCSimpleSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, videocore

There is a filter property on `VCSimpleSession` of type `VCFilter`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, VCFilter) {
    VCFilterNormal,
    VCFilterGray,
    VCFilterInvertColors,
    VCFilterSepia,
    VCFilterFisheye,
    VCFilterGlow
};
```

Where is the implementation for these filters?  How can I use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each filter lives in their own file in filters/Basic directory, and added at runtime with `FilterFactory.cpp`:

```
FilterFactory::FilterFactory() {
    {
        filters::BasicVideoFilterBGRA b;
        filters::GrayscaleVideoFilter g;
        filters::InvertColorsVideoFilter i;
        filters::SepiaVideoFilter s;
        filters::FisheyeVideoFilter f;
        filters::GlowVideoFilter gl;
    }
}
```

You can set the filters using the `setFilter:` method.  The [sample app](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore/blob/master/sample/SampleBroadcaster/SampleBroadcaster/ViewController.mm) iterates through all of the filters with a UIButton like so:

```
- (IBAction)btnFilterTouch:(id)sender {
    switch (_session.filter) {
        case VCFilterNormal:
            [_session setFilter:VCFilterGray];
            break;
        case VCFilterGray:
            [_session setFilter:VCFilterInvertColors];
            break;
        case VCFilterInvertColors:
            [_session setFilter:VCFilterSepia];
            break;
        case VCFilterSepia:
            [_session setFilter:VCFilterFisheye];
            break;
        case VCFilterFisheye:
            [_session setFilter:VCFilterGlow];
            break;
        case VCFilterGlow:
            [_session setFilter:VCFilterNormal];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: its included after 0.2.0 in cocoa pods and I can make the library work with 0.1.12 with Adobe FMS. How come you able to use this? Can you let me know how would I use the latest 0.3.2

Comment: @Saty you should ask a new question.